# How to compute quadratic roots given Euler's Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> Compute the quadratic roots of $w= e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$

I know that Euler's Identity is $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ and that
$re^{i\phi}=r\big( \cos\phi+ i\sin\phi\big)$.
However, I am not sure how to go about putting all the information together in order to compute the quadratic roots.

Comment: Find a representation of the sum in multiplicative form and apply De Moivre's formula

Comment: What do you mean by a quadratic root? why does this have a linear algebra tag

Comment: @MikhailGoltvanitsa I am new to this field of study.  What is a multiplicative form representation?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a $\theta$ such that $w=|w|\, e^{i\theta}$.
2. Find all the angles $\phi$ such that $e^{2i\phi} = e^{i\theta}$.
3. The roots are the numbers $z_\phi = \sqrt{|w|}\,e^{i\phi}$  (since $z_ϕ^2 = |w| e^{2i\phi} = |w| e^{i\theta} = w$)